# opensuse php fpm lighttpd 403 is it a permissions-issue

Tags: permissions, php-fpm, fastcgi, lighttpd, opensuse

So far I have configured php-fpm configured and is up and running listening to port 9000

lighttpd is running and serves static files the problem that I have seems to be a permissions issue, so i chmod 777 -R /srv when I try to access index.php (which has phpinfo()) I get "access denied" in the browser.

in my fastcgi.conf I have

```
server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )

fastcgi.server += ( ".php" =>
        ((
                "host" => "crunchyboy",
                "port" => 9000
        ))
)
```

if I use the browser to navigate to http://crunchyboy/index.php I get "Access Denied" that shows up in the access log as a 403 if i make up a file name like doesnotexist.php eg http://crunchyboy/doesnotexist.php I get a 404 file not found. If you are wondering about crunchyboy its the name of the machine and I can access it on the LAN. eg http://crunchyboy/index.html is ok

if I stop the php-fpm with systemctl stop php-fpm and navigate to index.php I get 503 Service Unavailable

so to me it looks like lighttpd is able to make a request to php-fpm but for some reason the file cannot be accessed.

I've configured php-fpm with nginx and apache in the past (more than 5 years ago) and did not have this problem.

I am really stuck with this, so would appreciate help or atleast ideas on what I need to look at.

Both lighttpd and php-fpm are set to run as user: lighttpd group:lighttpd Its on opensuse tumbleweed, recently updated

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `"check-local" => "false"` so that lighttpd does not try to access the .php file before sending the request to the PHP-FPM backend.

```
server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )

fastcgi.server += ( ".php" =>
        ((
                "host" => "crunchyboy",
                "port" => 9000,
                "check-local" => "false"
        ))
)
```